# IsDlg=1 is not working for custom list web part item to show in dialog

Tags: web-part

I have created custom list web part and using that web part in home page. when i click on item its not opening in dialog. I used below code.

Can anyone suggest me what is the problem ?

```
     SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                     query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'     Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
                            query.RowLimit = Convert.ToUInt16(RowLimit);
                            SPList list = web.Lists[ListName];
                            SPListItemCollection listItemsCollection = list.GetItems(query);
                            foreach (SPListItem listItem in listItemsCollection)
                            {
                                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                                TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();
                                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();

                                string docName = listItem.Title;
                                link.Text = docName;
                                try
                                {
                                   link.NavigateUrl = web.ParentWeb.Url  + list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "?id=" + listItem.ID + "&IsDlg=1";

                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    link.NavigateUrl = web.Url + list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "?id=" + listItem.ID ;
                                }

                                //link.Target = "_parent";
                                tableCell.Controls.Add(link);
                                tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
                                table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
                            }
                            this.Controls.Add(table);
```

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069102/how-to-edit-list-item-on-another-page

Answer (score 5):

When looking at the code I can't see anything that opens it in a dialog. Just ordinary links. Add "javascript:OpenDialog(here you puit that url) to link. Add this javascript as well:

The script can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

or here

```
function OpenDialog(url)
{

   //Using a generic object.
   var options = {
   title: "My Dialog Title",
   width: 400,
   height: 600,
   url: url };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

Comment: Addition: showModalDialog appends IsDlg=1 to the link provided, so no need to include that in the url parameter.

Comment: Thanks For ur reply. Can you tell me how to add and call javascript function in .ascx.cs file in .net 2012

Comment: You save the javascript in a js file which you deploy to either the hive or library. Then you reference it through the ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude. Info can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptinclude.aspx